# Android : Execute PHP file without opening web browser

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder

I'm trying to run a php file that is on a server, but I don't want my mobile browser to open to display it..

The first step is achieved through the code (c++):

```
   _di_JIntent MyPhp;
   MyPhp = TJIntent::JavaClass->init(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_VIEW,
   TJnet_Uri::JavaClass->parse(StringToJString("http://MyServer.es//UnoMApp.php")));
   SharedActivity()->startActivity(MyPhp);
```

It runs the php correctly but my mobile browser opens...

any ideas thanks

Comment: If you don't want the web browser to run, then don't ask Android to run it.  Use an HTTP API instead, such as Android's own `HttpURLConnection` class, or Embarcadero's `THTTPClient`, or Indy's `TIdHTTP` (Indy is pre-installed in C++Builder), or any number of other 3rd party HTTP libraries available for Android.

Comment: In the end I have followed your advice, I have used the 'Post' method of the Indy TIdhttp class (sending a null parameter) and it has worked perfectly.